SXA out of the box gallery component Rendering Variant issue
I am trying to use the gallery out of the box SXA component but want to change its structure by using the rendering variant, but when I added the new variant it did not work. The video and field data I am adding are not rendering on the page.
Is there any way to create or update the existing default rendering variant for the gallery component?


Can you post your code and screenshots of what you've changed in Sitecore?

If you're looking to modify the default rendering variant for the Gallery component directly, you can find it at the following location in the Sitecore content tree:
/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Rendering Variants/Rendering Variants/Gallery
You can navigate to this location and edit the default rendering variant directly. However, it's generally recommended to create custom variants instead of modifying default ones to maintain separation and avoid unintentional changes to default SXA functionality.

Yes you can change default rendering variant to your custom rendering variant . You need to create your custom rendering variant under rendering variant folder ==> gallery folder . You need to change rendering variant in presentation detail

Your custom rendering variant is visible in this dropdown , select it and save and publish .
it will be change structure .
Make sure you clear cache .
Hope this helps !

After creating rendering variant fields are not getting rendered on page, but is visible in experience editor.

Did you publish those fields data ? they are available on CD site ? Try publishing related item it will resolve or check in another browser or incognito tab

Everything i  have published but field values are not rendered on the page.

Did you cleared cache ?

Default rendering variant for the Gallery component is located on the below location:
/sitecore/system/Settings/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Rendering Variants/Rendering Variants/Gallery


You can make edit on above variant to reflect your changes.
Hope this helps!!!

I have tried but passing new field data is not rendered on page.

@Gagan Can you please shapshot the fields you added on the variant if possible.

I have shared the screenshot above what field data i want to render.
